# how to refactor same class with different version params

Tags: java, refactoring

like two class below,they are almost looks same except invoke different version of params,so how to refactor them?

```
import com.v1.B;
import com.v1.C;
class A1
{
  public A1(B,C)
  public dosomething1()
  {
    //do something with B and C
  }
  public dosomething2()
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Class A2:

```
import com.v2.B;
import com.v2.C;
class A2
{
  public A2(B,C)
  public dosomething1()
  {
    //do something with B and C
  }
  public dosomething2()
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean 'invoke different version of param'?

Comment: I mean using different version of param,like B and C above

Comment: if the only difference is the params then you don't need two classes. In your example the body of both classes is the same

Comment: but they will be used in method dosomething1

Comment: Then use composition or inheritance to just override `doSomething1` in class A2. The main point is that you should always avoid duplicate code. If it is common, it should be in the top class, for example `doSomething2`. The bottom class should be for "deviations" or special cases of the common code

Answer (score 1):

you should first create a base class or interface for both types e.g. `com.v.BaseB` for `com.v1.B` and `com.v2.B` to facilitate polymorphism and then you can use a single generic class without any duplication like:

```
import com.v.B;
import com.v.C;
class A
{
  public A(B,C)
  public dosomething1()
  {
    //do something with B and C
  }
  public dosomething2()
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```